# Do singletons have any sense in Objective-c context?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I come from java/cpp environment where singletons do have their advantages over class(static) methods, however in objective-c because of it's dynamic nature, from my past observation there is really no advantage in using a singleton over a class method. Could someone confirm this, or maybe give examples where a singleton can do something that a class method can't(but excepting the case in which a singleton is in fact a 'multiton")

EDIT: I know what singletons and class methods are and it's not a matter of concept, more like: can a class method fully replace a singleton in objective-c, rendering the singleton implementation useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons are used in Objective-C.  In the Cocoa framework, NSApplication, NSDocumentController, and NSWorkspace are examples of singletons.

The advantage of using a singleton over a class method is that the behavior of a singleton can be changed by making a subclass.  It is somewhat rare, but some applications do make subclasses of NSDocumentController or NSApplication.  (For example, you may wish to override the NSDocument `-documentClassForType:` method).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dietrich, good points and good examples. However, you can "override" a class method too by using categories. The `NSApplication`, `NSDocumentController` are good examples that make me think that there must be a reason for which they choose to do it so. In any case, what I'm trying to find out is that if I'm going to start using class methods instead of singletons will I run in to trouble later? Is this a good decision? I sure thing like class methods better because need absolutely no additional setup and are better looking. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: If you override methods using categories, how do you call the original method?  With subclassing, you can use `super`.